# Patch for Non-ASCII Characters

Tags: file-browser

My OS (WIN7) uses non ASCII characters in the file system. Doesn't have to, but does.

I know in general it's not a great idea, but some of my directories have names which use these characters.

Blender shows it all non-readable gibberish, which makes it pretty difficult to understand what directory I'm looking at.

Is there some kind of UTF-8 patch, or update to help out here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Blender does display unicode (utf8 and latin1), try change the system user-preferences to enable 'international fonts'.

This loads a font with a wider range of characters that may display your paths correctly.

Comment: Heh, completely forgot to check this setting in the freshly downloaded blender installation I had. Older versions I have this already set, but indeed, showing them paths with this goes OK.

Comment: Note: I had to upgrade from version 2.5x - then I found it

Comment: Though, still shows RTL backwards...