# How can a text object be created with non ASCII characters?

Tags: modeling, text-object

After enabling [international fonts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195/patch-for-non-ascii-characters) I was expecting that I could create a text object like: 咏春拳.

It seems that a different font is used for the text object.

[image]

The *Outliner* shows a font `Bfont`

[image]

Can this be changed?

Comment: Text font can be changed from the **Object Data** panel.

Comment: @Leon do you mean *Object Font*?

Comment: Yes. I think you are going to create something like [this](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=66572)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fonts for creating Text objects are set in the Text Data panel.

[image]

Blender uses `droidsans_final_fixed.ttf` (font name: **DejaVuSans**) as the detault i18n font, but just for UI text display, located in blender folder `..//2.69\datafiles\fonts\`. There also another font called `bmonofont-i18n.ttf` (font name: **BlenderMonoI18n**) In the same folder. You can use it as the font for the Text object if you didn't have any other unicode or asian fonts in hand. Ortherwise, you have to use other system or non-system fonts to create the solid text mesh.

As for the builtin `Bfont.ttf`, it uses standard encoding, and less than 200KB. I don't think it is possible to include the large number of non-ascii charset.

Comment: I used arialuni.ttf from \Windows\Fonts it has 22MB and seems to contain everything.